# Lightbox2 doesn't show image

Tags: views, 7, javascript

I have Lightbox2 installed on my Drupal Project. I am trying to use lightbox2 through links, for example:

`<a href="/absolute-path-to-image" rel="lightbox">
   Link
</a>`

It works only when I turn on the Lite version. How can I make it work on normal one? I have read that there is a possibility of wrong path. Already checked all of the possibilities and I can confirm it's not that. Is it possible that it collide with jQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I think.. It will help to u.. Use views module and add image fields and rewrite the image fields. Look this image nkana-> database name.